# why i have syntax error when i use sql in my node.js code

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, syntax, discord.js

```
"SELECT IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
       WHERE TABLE_NAME = `"+message.author.id+"` ));"
```

I have a syntax error in this statement that I can't seem to identify Any thoughts?

Error :

```
Something is wrong in your syntax near ') LIMIT 0, 25' in line 2
```

I use this mysql statment in node.js code

```
con.query("SELECT IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
       WHERE TABLE_NAME = `"+message.author.id+"` ));", async function (err, result) {
             console.log(result);
                if (err) throw err;
                if(result== undefined)
                {
                  con.query("CREATE TABLE `"+message.author.id+"` ( id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, anime_name varchar(255), date DATE,count int(11), );");


                }
```

Comment: You really should parameterize your SQL instead of doing concatenation. Would prevent SQL injection issues down the road.

Answer (score 0):

IT is because your concatenation is wrong if you want to do concatenations it should be like this.

```
   let a = "SELECT IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME ="+message.author.id+"));"
   //In case you want to do it as template string it should be like
   let a = `SELECT IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
         WHERE TABLE_NAME = ${message.author.id} ));`
```